# I get cannot resolve imports although my dependency is present in package.json What could be the error?

Tags: reactjs, frontend, dependencies

[image]

Here is the code for  my package.json  . I have attached the logs for the error that i get

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@emailjs/browser": "^3.11.0",
    "@react-three/drei": "^9.68.2",
    "@react-three/fiber": "^8.13.0",
    "framer-motion": "^10.12.8",
    "maath": "^0.5.3",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.11.1",
    "react-tilt": "^1.0.2",
    "react-vertical-timeline-component": "^3.6.0",
    "three": "^0.152.2"
```

Comment: Did you run `npm install`? Also try restarting vite if you didn't already.

Comment: I did . Nothing worked . I think it was a dependency version compatiblity issue .